# Java/android change http-s to link style

Tags: java, android

```
String s="asd http://www.blabla.com/bla/foo wert fgh";
```

I want a string:

```
asd <a href='http://www.blabla.com/bla/foo'>http://www.blabla.com/bla/foo</a> wert fgh
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you actually want to do is to display the text with links to the user, then the [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class does what you want; load a TextView with the string, run Linkify on it, and any URLs will become clickable.

If you really do want a String containing the marked-up links, then I don't know any easy way to do it. Create a Spannable, use Linkify on it, and then parse the Spannable out to HTML, perhaps? Or you could just roll your own using regular expressions.